# How to start flashlight in cordova ios & android?

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

How can I start the flashlight in cordova ios & android?

I've found this pluging: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Flashlight-PhoneGap-Plugin but besides the fact that is not maintained anymore, it doesn't work either. It is not a permission problem, as my camera works properly in both ios and anroid.

my devices are:

```
iphone 6s running ios 14.7.1

samsung s7 running lineageOS 19
```

In android I've managed to turn on the flashlight using javascript, but this is not supported in ios.

Are there any other options out there?

Thanks

Comment: Some more details, while debugging the phonegap plugin I've noticed that at some point it throws this error:  android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4): setTorchMode:2031: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user. So it turns out this plugin only works if the camera is not in use. This behavior is not very helpful for my usecase.